# psycopg2 "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert binary data (a whirlpool hash) into a PG table and am getting an error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

code:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO
        sessions
        (identity_hash, posted_on)
    VALUES
        (%s, NOW())
""", identity_hash)
```

I tried adding conn.Binary("identity_hash") to the variable before insertion, but get the same error.

The identity_hash column is a bytea.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the "examples/binary.py" script in the psycopg2 source distribution? It works fine here. It looks a bit different than your excerpt:

```
data1 = {'id':1, 'name':'somehackers.jpg',
     'img':psycopg2.Binary(open('somehackers.jpg').read())}

curs.execute("""INSERT INTO test_binary
              VALUES (%(id)s, %(name)s, %(img)s)""", data1)
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for the pyscopg2 manual unsuccessfully. I assumed the lib worked in a similar way to MySQLdb, but I guess it doesn't..

Comment: From the manual: "For positional variables binding, the second argument must *always* be a sequence, even if it contains a single variable. *And remember that Python requires a comma to create a single element tuple* "  -- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 32):

The problem you have is that you are passing the object as second parameter: the second parameters should be either a tuple or a dict. There is no shortcut as in the % string operator.

You should do:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO
        sessions
        (identity_hash, posted_on)
    VALUES
        (%s, NOW())
""", (identity_hash,))
```

Comment: ugh, this is the gotcha that got me - this seems to me more relevant than the accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

Encountered the same problem and found that this is actually covered in their [FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html)

> I try to execute a query but it fails with the error not all arguments
>   converted during string formatting (or object does not support
>   indexing). Why? Psycopg always require positional arguments to be
>   passed as a sequence, even when the query takes a single parameter.
>   And remember that to make a single item tuple in Python you need a
>   comma! See Passing parameters to SQL queries.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", "bar")    # WRONG
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar"))  # WRONG
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar",)) # correct
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ["bar"])  # correct
```

Comment: Thanks, Man. Simple and straightforward answer. 